# Bootstrap glyph icons files

Tags: image, file, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons, file-location

I have a MVC 5 internet application that uses Bootstrap 3.0. I have a android application that links into a webservice for the internet application.

My question is this: Where are the Bootstrap glyph icons stored? I wish to add some of these glyph icons to my android application, yet cannot find the files for these glyph icons.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glyphicons are part of Bootstrap, you don't really need to worry about it. If you look through their fantastic documentation you can simply reference them through classes. EG:

```
<button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></button>
```

This would make a simple button with the "cog" icon from bootstrap. You can browse through alternatives to use as you wish.

Comment: I need the fileName for the android application. Is it possible to get the glyph icons as files?

Comment: They should be under the "fonts" directory in your application.

Comment: Is it possible/allowed to extract the files from the main file?

Comment: Using different icons, but this should help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Psq-GHed-Oc#t=199